# Rails ActiveAdmin routing problem at index page with renamed resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, inherited-resources

I have an index page:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Activity do
  config.sort_order = ''
  belongs_to :specialist, optional: true
  belongs_to :activities_category, optional: true
end
```

And I have another index page for the same but renamed resource:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Activity, as: 'ModeratedActivity' do
  config.sort_order = 'updated_at_asc'
  actions :index, :show
  belongs_to :specialist, optional: true
  belongs_to :activities_category, optional: true
  ...
end
```

These pages have totally different index tables, filters and permissions.

The problem is that id_colunm, index actions and filters form of ModeratedActivity page route to Activity page actions.

For example: filters form on ModeratedActivity page should route to:

**/admin/moderated_activities?[filter_params]**

But actually route to:

**/admin/activities?[filter_params]**

Tried to change controller defaults on ModeratedActivity page:

```
controller do
  defaults :route_collection_name => "moderated_activities", route_instance_name: "moderated_activity", :collection_name => 'moderated_activities', :instance_name => 'moderated_activity', :resource_class => Activity
  ...
end
```

Didn't help.

Comment: Hi. Can you please share details of the Activity model? How do `Activity` and `ModeratedActivity` differ?

Comment: I tested this scenario with rails 5.2.3, activeadmin 2.0.0 and I was not able to reproduce it. I registered two pages with the same model, one aliased and both route correctly to their index / show routes.

Comment: @Tomáš Landovský I really didn't mention important details, sorry for that. I found the reason: ModeratedActivity page has two belongs_to statements and if I remove them everythig works correctly.

Comment: All is well then! All the best.